# SPSS Max function for multiple variables

Tags: spss

For a list of three variables I want to store the highest/maximum variable value in a target variable. Reading the `Command Syntax Reference` I thought the correct function would be `COUNT`, but it doesn't seem to work. I want a function like MAX(v1, v2, v3) to produce the following results:

```
v1 v2 v3    target
1  4  2     4
4  1  7     7
2  6  9     9
1  .  15    15
.  .  .     .
```

What function should I use?

Comment: why do you feel `count ` would return the intended result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compute target  = max(v1 to v3).